# Print JavaScript code from external file

Tags: javascript, xss

I am trying to understand how to include JavaScript externally so the code prints to the page.

When I insert the JavaScript directly into the page code, it prints "hello"

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">document.write("hello");</script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I put that same code into external file say "javascript.js" and include it (src) in the html it does not print "hello"?

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://thewebsite.com/javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to understand how to get that external JavaScript file to run and print "hello". 
How does XSS work then if a hacker was to include the following tag inside say a `textarea` to call his malicious script from malicious server?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://thewebsite.com/javascript.js"></script>
```

Heres whats in the "javascript.js" file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("hello");
</script>
```

The file is on the same domain so Same Origin Policy should not apply here and as mentioned if I directly insert code it does work but not when I try to include as separate file.

I thought including JavaScript as external file, should print the contents of the external file (i.e. "hello" in this case) as if it was directly inserted in html page?

Comment: Could you tell what you get on the console? And which browser you are using. I am able to get what you are trying to do.

Comment: You don't need <script> tag inside your javascript file

Comment: Firefox browser 3.6.18 and nothing gets printed to screen. I am trying to do a dummy XSS, I have a textarea on page and I insert the JavaScript src tag to try to get it to print "hello" to page, from the code in the external file included by src.

Comment: Thanks Ajai, you solved it, the <Script> tag inside external javascript file was problem. taking it out makes it run!

Comment: You insert javascript src tag? I am sorry I am not able to understand. If you want to perform a persistent xss attack you need to inject the entire js code into the textarea which goes unparsed and gets stored in the server.So anyone who visits your profile will get the script executed in their login. This is how xss persistent attack works. Now when you try to load an external js file you need to include the entire script `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://thewebsite.com/javascript.js"></script>` and not just the src of javascript tag(I don't know what that means but anyways)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess there is a policy enforced by browsers called `Same Origin Policy` which makes sure that JS from different domains does not access each others data when loaded in a single page. Lets say that you have a Google Ad and it has some Javascript in it. It wouldn't be advisable if the script in Google Ads be able to access the data in your site (Vice-Versa but ofcourse you always have Google Ads or the Like button as iFrame and hence anyways they are most neatly seperated.)

If you could load the js file as a src to image file then I suppose you can achieve what you intend to.(If I am not wrong.)

Edit: The javascript file cannot be given as input to the src of img tag. You can only use it as `javascript:` scheme.

Comment: The "javascript.js" file is on the same domain, so SOP should not effect this

Comment: Also, that isn't how the SOP works. If you load a script from google.com then you are trusting Google not to put anything in that script that will harm you. The script has full access to all the data on your Origin because that is the context in which it is executing.

Comment: You can't use a JavaScript file as a src to an image. The JS file would be requested, seen to not be an image, and discarded (with the img element's onerror function firing). You *could* use a `javascript:` scheme URI as the src to an image (in which all the JS is included in the URI itself and not loaded over HTTP) but most browsers will discard those as they are rarely useful and a common source of JavaScript for authors to fail to protect against when asking for user generated content.

Comment: Well Google Ads is just an example. I was referring to general Ads placement in webpage. Does that mean I am allowing all the Third-party ads to be placed in my page and allow them to access whatever data they need?

Comment: If you are including them by dropping a `<script>` element into the page, then yes, you are.

Answer (score 0):

> When I insert the JavaScript directly into the page code, it prints "hello"

Correct

> However, when I put that same code into external file say "javascript.js" and include it (src) in the html it does not print "hello"?

If the content isn't being written then, presumably, an error is being thrown instead. Check the error console for your browser.

The problem is that you are including the HTML script tags in the JavaScript file. JavaScript files should contain *only* JavaScript.

> The file is on the same domain so Same Origin Policy should not apply here

It doesn't. The Same Origin Policy just prevents JavaScript running (not loaded from) Origin A from reading data from Origin B. Since the data is included in the script itself, it would still be available, even if the script was loaded from Origin B.